# How to make an object an attribute of another object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oop, database-design, model

Is there a way to make a Rails model have another model as an attribute?

E.g. I have a User model with an address attribute, and the address attribute in the User model is its own class.

```
User Model
----------       
lastName:string                 
firstname:string               
address: addressModel

Address Model
-------------
street: string 
city:string
zipCode:integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Note that for this to work you need to have a `user_id` field in your addresses table.

This will magically give your user object an address attribute of type Address. It also allows you to assign an address to a user. E.g.:

```
address = Address.find(1)
user = User.find(1)
user.address = address
user.save

user.address.class # => Address
user.address.id # => 1
```

This is an example of a 1:1 association between user and address. Check the guide I linked to above for explanations about other types of association.

Comment: Awesome, yea I wasn't sure if it had to be an association or if you could make the attribute's type another class. Im tracking the user_id should auto generate with the rails generator for the model. And thanks for the link, that'll come in useful.